# Pandas: Creating new Dataframe and writing to new CSV

Tags: pandas

I think I know how to do this but I'm experiencing a bug where I get the dataframe I want but when I write the new dataframe to a csv, the original dataframe is written instead of the new one.

Goal: read csv into dataframe, pull out all rows filtered by values in two different columns (I'm good on this).  Then I want to write this new dataframe to a new csv.

To create the new dataframe, I have done:

```
df_new = df.loc[(df['column1'] == 0.0) & (df['column2'] != 1)]
df_new.describe()
#this yields the correct results

df_new.to_csv('new_csv.csv')
```

The new csv has the original dataframe's data in it.

Can someone help me here?

Comment: That should not be possible. Is there any other code between the creation of `df_new` and its being written to CSV?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no code in between

Comment: The only way that this can happen is if there is no way to split `df` based on the clause that you've given it `(df['column1']==0.0) & (df['column2']!=1)`. In that case `new_df` would just be a replica of `df`.

Comment: So I figured out the issue.  I literally just had to restart the Jupyter console.  I find that to be a pretty annoying glitch.